# How to do method overriding in Object-C

Tags: objective-c, oop, subclass, overloading

I am trying to do a class extension and calling the extended method from a generic method. I'm just wondering if it's possible to do it? Below is my code.

ClassA.h:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

-(void) method;
```

ClassA.m:

```
#import "ClassA.h"

-(void) method{
    NSLog(@"do A");
}
```

ClassB.h:

```
@interface ClassB : ClassA

-(void) method;
```

ClassB.m:

```
#import "ClassB.h"

-(void) method{
    NSLog(@"do B");
}
```

and in MainClass.m

```
-(void) doMethod {
    ClassA *class = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    [class method];
}
```

I tried to do something like this, but nothing was print out. Is it possible to do this? and will it print out "do B"??

Comment: Post your actual code please (this one does not compile). Also, this question is about method overriding, not class extension. You shoul fix your title and tags to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code compiles and runs fine (minus a small typo in **@interface ClassA.h** that should be **@interface ClassA**):

```
cristi:tmp diciu$ cat test.m
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ClassA : NSObject
- (void) method;
@end

@interface ClassB : ClassA
-(void) method;
@end

@implementation ClassA
-(void) method{
    NSLog(@"do A");
}
@end

@implementation ClassB
-(void) method{
    NSLog(@"do B");
}
@end

int main()
{
    ClassA *class = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    [class method];
}
cristi:tmp diciu$ gcc test.m -framework Cocoa
cristi:tmp diciu$ ./a.out 
2012-06-21 15:04:22.652 a.out[14408:707] do B
```

Apple's Objective-C docs contain a chapter on how inheritance works that is available online [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-86370).